# Firestore listener subscription triggers random number of times

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

I have a Firestore listener that seems to trigger a random number of times. On the first page load, it might trigger 5 times, refreshing the page and it fires 13 times.

```js
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class AuthService {

  user$: BehaviorSubject<SavedUser | undefined> = new BehaviorSubject<SavedUser | undefined>(undefined);

  constructor(private angularFireAuth: AngularFireAuth, private firestore: AngularFirestore, private router: Router) {
    this.onAuthStateChanged();
  }

  onAuthStateChanged() {

    let counter = 0;

    this.angularFireAuth.authState.subscribe(user => {
      if (user) {
        this.firestore
          .collection('user')
          .doc<User>(user.uid)
          .valueChanges()
          .subscribe(userRecord => {
            counter++

            console.log(counter); // Testing

            user.getIdToken(true);

            this.user$.next(userRecord);
          });
      }
    });
  }
}
```

The output of the console log:

```
auth.service.ts:35 1
auth.service.ts:35 2
auth.service.ts:35 3
auth.service.ts:35 4
auth.service.ts:35 5
auth.service.ts:35 6
auth.service.ts:35 7
auth.service.ts:35 8
auth.service.ts:35 9
auth.service.ts:35 10
auth.service.ts:35 11
```

All I'm looking to do here is refresh the user's token when the document it's backed by changes.

I know the `this.angularFireAuth.onAuthStateChanged(user => {...}` is only triggered once, and no changes are happening to the document.

I've tried unsubscribing from the Firestore subscription via `onDestroy` however that made no difference.

As a "fix" I thought I would be able to read the first value and stop processing via

```js
this.firestore
  .collection('user')
  .doc<User>(user.uid)
  .valueChanges()
  .pipe(first())
  .subscribe(userRecord => {...});
```

Which did work at first sight, however that stops the `.valueChanges()` from triggering when the document is later changed.

Any tips?

Comment: do you have only one instance of your AuthService created?

Comment: Yeah, it's an injected service so I assume so; If I had additional instances of it, I'd assume the number of times it triggered would be consistent between refreshes?

Comment: how did you measure that "Firestore listener that seems to trigger a random number of times"? in most of the cases the question assumption isn't correct

Comment: Updated to show, is my testing method just wrong?

Comment: it is correct, but it doesn't give all of the information required yet. could you also check how many times `authState` is changed?

Comment: Using the same method but placing the counter just before `if(user)` the result is always 1 as expected

Comment: is sounds for me like your app is updating a user item in the 'users' collection at the startup several times for some reason

Comment: Watching the record in the Firestore console I'm not seeing the record change, and I've also got nothing in the codebase which writes to the user document... hence my confusion :)

Comment: Removing `user.getIdToken(true)` stops it firing again however I'm not seeing thee correlation between the auth user and the user record I'm watching for changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I've solved my actual problem by setting a timestamp on the object via another firestore listener, then comparing the current and previous to only trigger once.

I'll post this code if anyone comes here doing a similar thing, but I'd still want to find out why my subscriber is going off so many times.

Cloud function:

```js
export class UserUpdateListener {

  public listen = functions.firestore
    .document('user/{uid}')
    .onWrite(async (snapshot) => {

      const before: User = snapshot.before.data() as User;
      const after: User = snapshot.after.data() as User;

      const skipUpdate = before.lastUpdate && after.lastUpdate && !before.lastUpdate.isEqual(after.lastUpdate);
      if (skipUpdate) {
        functions.logger.info('No changes, skipping timestamp update');
        return;
      }

      await snapshot.after.ref.update({ lastUpdate: admin.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp() });
    });
}
```

I then check the timestamp in my client using:

```js
constructor(private angularFireAuth: AngularFireAuth, private firestore: AngularFirestore, private router: Router) {
  this.onAuthStateChanged();

  let lastUpdate: Timestamp;

  this.user$.subscribe(async (user) => {
    if (this.authUser && user && user.lastUpdate) {
      if (lastUpdate && !user.lastUpdate.isEqual(lastUpdate)) {
        await this.authUser.getIdToken(true);
      }
      lastUpdate = user.lastUpdate;
    }
  });
}
```

Hopefully this will save someone some time.